# Create Daemonset using kubectl?

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, daemonset

I took the CKA exam and I needed to work with Daemonsets for quite a while there. Since it is much faster to do everything with kubectl instead of creating yaml manifests for k8s resources, I was wondering if it is possible to create Daemonset resources using `kubectl`.

I know that it is NOT possible to create it using regular `kubectl create daemonset` at least for now. And there is no description of it in the documentation. But maybe there is a way to do that in some different way?

The best thing I could do right now is to create Deployment first like `kubectl create deployment` and edit it's output manifest. Any options here?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

CKA allows access to [K8S documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/home/). So, it should be possible to get a sample YAML for different resources from there. [Here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/) is the one for the Daemonset from K8S documentation.

Also, not sure if the certification environment has access to resources in the kube-system namespace. If yes, then use the below command to get a sample yaml for Daemonset.

> kubectl get daemonsets kube-flannel-ds-amd64 -o yaml -n=kube-system > daemonset.yaml

Comment: this command may produce a YAML which is a bit cumbersome as it will have way too many things in it from the current daemonset and you will have to make sure you check every attribute to not cause any kind of undesired overlap.

I think @zamansakib 's way ( https://stackoverflow.com/a/56097744/636762 ) of creating a dry-run deployment yaml and then just changing the kind gives a cleaner new yaml

Answer (score 19):

The fastest hack is to create a deployment file using

```
kubectl create deploy nginx --image=nginx --dry-run -o yaml > nginx-ds.yaml
```

Now replace the line `kind: Deployment` with `kind: DaemonSet` in **nginx-ds.yaml** and remove the line `replicas: 1`

However, the following command will give a clean daemonset manifest considering that "apps/v1" is the api used for DaemonSet in your cluster

```
kubectl create deploy nginx --image=nginx --dry-run -o yaml | \
    sed '/null\|{}\|replicas/d;/status/,$d;s/Deployment/DaemonSet/g' > nginx-ds.yaml
```

You have your nginx DaemonSet.

Comment: It also comes with different apiversion and some unwanted fields. change api version to extensions/v1beta1 and use "--validate=false" with the kubectl apply to suppress warnings.

Comment: The examples in the documents are more extensive than necessary

Comment: An improvement - you also need to remove **strategy: {}** property from generated deployment's yaml

Answer (score 6):

The fastest way to create

```bash
kubectl create deploy nginx --image=nginx --dry-run -o yaml > nginx-ds.yaml
```

Now replace the line kind: Deployment with kind: DaemonSet in nginx-ds.yaml and remove the line **replicas: 1**, **strategy {}** and **status {}** as well.
Otherwise, it shows an error for some required fields like this

```
error: error validating "nginx-ds.yaml": error validating data: [ValidationError(DaemonSet.spec): unknown field "strategy" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DaemonSetSpec, ValidationError(DaemonSet.status): missing required field "currentNumberScheduled" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DaemonSetStatus,ValidationError(DaemonSet.status): missing required field "numberMisscheduled" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DaemonSetStatus, ValidationError(DaemonSet.status): missing required field "desiredNumberScheduled" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DaemonSetStatus, ValidationError(DaemonSet.status): missing required field "numberReady" in io.k8s.api.apps.v1.DaemonSetStatus]; if you choose to ignore these errors, turn validation off with --validate=false
```

Answer (score 4):

It's impossible. At least for Kubernetes 1.12. The only option is to get a sample Daemonset yaml file and go from there.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such option to create a DaemonSet using `kubectl`. But still, you can prepare a Yaml file with basic configuration for a DaemonSet, e.g. `daemon-set-basic.yaml`, and create it using `kubectl create -f daemon-set-basic.yaml`

You can edit new DaemonSet using `kubectl edit daemonset <name-of-the-daemon-set>`. Or modify the Yaml file and apply changes by `kubectl apply -f daemon-set-basic.yaml`. Note, if you want to update configuration modifying file and using `apply` command, it is better to use `apply` instead of `create` when you create the DaemonSet.

Here is the example of a simple DaemonSet:

```
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: fluentd-elasticsearch
  labels:
    k8s-app: fluentd-logging
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: fluentd-elasticsearch
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: fluentd-elasticsearch
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: fluentd-elasticsearch
        image: k8s.gcr.io/fluentd-elasticsearch:1.20
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. Yes, it is easy to create a daemonset using yaml, this is what I do most of the time. The problem with that is that I should create that file manually, which I'm too lazy to do :) .  Seems like I should create a PR to kubernetes repo and try to implement that. Thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You could take advantage of Kubernetes architecture to obtain definition of **DaemonSet** from existing cluster. Have a look at `kube-proxy`, which is a network component that runs on each node in your cluster. [image] 
`kube-proxy` is deployed as **DaemonSet** so you can extract its definition with below command.

```sh
$ kubectl get ds kube-proxy -n kube-system -o yaml > kube-proxy.ds.yaml
```

**Warning!**
By extracting definition of **DaemonSet** from `kube-proxy` be aware that:

1. You will have to do pliantly of clean up!
2. You will have to change apiVersion from `extensions/v1beta1` to `apps/v1`

Answer (score 0):

I used this by the following commands:

1. Either create Replicaset or deployment from Kubernetes imperative command

kubectl create deployment  <daemonset_name> --image= --dry-run -o yaml > file.txt

2. Edit the kind and replace DaemonSet, remove replicas and strategy fields into it.
3. `kubectl apply -f file.txt`

Answer (score 0):

During CKA examination you are allowed to access [Kubernetes Documentation for DaemonSets](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/). You could use the link and get examples of DaemonSet yaml files. However you could use the way you mentioned, change a deployment specification to DaemonSet specification. You need to change the **kind** to **Daemonset**, remove *strategy, replicas and status* fields. That would do.

Answer (score -1):

Using command to deployment create and modifying it,  one can create daemonset very quickly. 
Below is one line command to create daemonset

```
kubectl create deployment elasticsearch --namespace=kube-system  --image=k8s.gcr.io/fluentd-elasticsearch:1.20 --dry-run -o yaml | grep -v "creationTimestamp\|status" | awk '{gsub(/Deployment/, "DaemonSet"); print }'
```

Comment: You didn't remove replicas :)